# getting a return outside function syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Im writing a code for DNA base pairs but I am constantly getting 
a Syntax Error saying return outside function. On line 10

```
    def is_base_pair(base1, base2):

   base1 = base1.upper()
base2 = base2.upper()

for i in range(0, len(base1)):

   if base1[i] == "T" and base2[i] == "A":

      return True

   if base1[i] == "A" and base2[i] == "T":

      return True

   if base1[i] == "G" and  base2[i] == "C":

      return True

   if base1[i] == "C" and base2[i] == "G":

      return True
```

Comment: Pretty self explanatory; `return` isn't inside the function. You should indent it until it is. The code snippet you've provided is pretty atrocious btw, format it in order for it to depict how you've really written it.

Comment: im new to coding as you can tell, so im still learning how to write properly.

Comment: The important thing to know for python is, whitespace matters. It is used to define scope.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a indentation dependent language: it uses indentation to delimit blocks. Here your method block is not indented properly.

So very simple answer: use a tab aware and properly configured editor. Make sure that tab and spaces are displayed differently. Then indent your code properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help!